# Notification of TFS checkin when I open a solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Is there a way (possibly a plugin) for VS which would notify you via pop up when you open a solution, and any of the files that you currently have are out of date (i.e. you should run a get latest)?

Ideally this would also work for branches as well. For example, I branch the entire solution. Now I'm working away, but I don't want to wait until working on something for a week before I know that there were changes in the main branch. I'd rather find out when I open the solution and get to see what was changed and decide on whether or not to merge down.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way for force it to get the latest code when you open a solution.  It's not exactly a pop-up, but i think it's what you're asking for:

```
Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Environment -> Get everything when solution or project is opened
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't want to automatically get everything when a solution is opened. I want to check to see if there is anything I might want to get.

Comment: That sounds like a non-automated solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, even though it gets everything, it will not just trash what you currently have out for edit.  You'll be asked to merge the code.

Comment: What I want automated is the notification that there are newer files. Are there any commands from within VS which can do a "show me what Get Latest will do, but don't do it?"

Comment: No - although in Source Control Exporer there is a "Latest" flag